# Excel dynamic range offset formula exclude #n/a

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula, offset

I have data that changes depending on the slicer, and I can't figure out the correct offset formula to select only data values that are valid or in other words, exclude any #N/A values. The data looks something like this:

```
|Column A   |  Column B   |Column C|
|----------------------------------|
|Jan        |   #N/A      |    #N/A|
|Feb        |   4         |     40 |
|Mar        |   5         |    38  |
|Apr        |   12        |     10 |
|May        |   #N/A      |    #N/A|
|Jun        |   #N/A      |    #N/A|
```

I want the offset range to select only Feb/Mar/Apr rows. But if the data changes because I click on a different filter (example below), I want it to still select only the non-error data (rows Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr):

```
|Column A   |  Column B  | Column C|
|----------------------------------|
|Jan        |   30       |      60 |
|Feb        |   8        |      83 |
|Mar        |   53       |      14 |
|Apr        |   11       |      41 |
|May        |   #N/A     |     #N/A|
|Jun        |   #N/A     |     #N/A|
```

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: what do you want to do with the non-error data? aggregate has many subfunctions that can be made to ignore errors.

Comment: do the non-error rows come continuously one after other or there can be an error row(s) in between?

Comment: @Jeeped i want the offset function to select the non-error data to make a graph, and the graph will change according to the slicer.

Comment: @Karpak as of now i've only seen error either after the values, or both before and after (as shown in examples above). is there a way to have the offset function select whatever data is available (non #N/A values) regardless of where it's located within the columns?

Comment: @Joyce, there could be a direct formula, I remember exploring similar to this few years ago. But couldn't recollect, what I did and how I did. However there is a round about way. I provided that as the answer to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset function can only select a single range of cells, however this should still be suitable for your needs. A graph with months along the x-axis should include all months even if there isn't a value. The offset function will just cause the graph to start at the earliest month with a value and finish at the latest month with a value. Any months in between without a value will just have nothing plotted on the chart.

To use named ranges in a chart, you have to name each individual series. You can't use a dynamic range for the entire chart source data range.

Define the following three named ranges for use in your chart. There is one named range for each column A, B and C. Each named range looks at Column B to determine which rows to include:

Months:

```
=IF(COUNT(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)=0,Sheet1!$A$2,OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,MIN(IF(ISERROR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7),"",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)))-1,0,MAX(IF(ISERROR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7),"",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)))-MIN(IF(ISERROR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7),"",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)))+1,1))
```

Series1:

```
=IF(COUNT(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)=0,Sheet1!$B$2,OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,MIN(IF(ISERROR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7),"",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)))-1,0,MAX(IF(ISERROR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7),"",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)))-MIN(IF(ISERROR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7),"",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)))+1,1))
```

Series2:

```
=IF(COUNT(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)=0,Sheet1!$C$2,OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$1,MIN(IF(ISERROR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7),"",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)))-1,0,MAX(IF(ISERROR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7),"",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)))-MIN(IF(ISERROR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7),"",ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)))+1,1))
```

You can then set up your chart, but remember you need to add/edit each series individually. Ignore the Chart Data Range field:

[image: Chart]

When you set each series or x-axis to the named range, you need to qualify it with a reference to the current worksheet or workbook. If you just specify the range name, Excel won't recognize it:

[image: Edit Series]

[image: Axis Label]

After you have set everything up, the Chart Data Range field will show the consolidated range that covers all data for your change. Do not touch this field. The dynamic ranges have been set for the series. As your data changes, FMS will automatically recalculate the Chart Data Range.

[image: Updated Range]

Comment: Hi, I have a follow up question: I have a bar graph of these values and when all the values in columns B & C are #N/A I receive the error "Excel Found a problem with one or more formula references in this worksheet". Do you know a way to change the offset formulas to get rid of this error? Thank you.

Comment: Hi. I've updated the formulas, wrapping them in an IF statement that checks if column B is all errors. If it is, then the named ranges will refer to the first row of data instead of returning an error. This will cause the chart to show Jan with no bars and no error message. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Joyce, You can create an additional set of cells with same dimension and use those cells in your offset. For creating the additional set of cells. Choose any one cell and enter the below formula as Array formula. (Enter the below formula and then press shift + enter). Then copy that cell to all other cells as mentioned in the attached image. Then you can base that new set of cells in your offset. I believe, this will address your requirements. No matter whether the rows or continuous or errors in between.  If you use the offset function of the new set of cells, which would have only the non-error data and you can make a graph using that, and the graph will change according to the slicer. Only assumption that I made is that, if it is error both column B and Column C will have the error value. So, it filters only based on the value in column B.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$10,SMALL(IF(ISERROR($B$2:$B$10),"",ROW($B$2:$B$10)),ROW(A1)),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: clever, I would not have thought of this method - thank you so much!

Comment: Urw. If you are fine with not seeing the error data in the original set of cells, the smart way could be  creating those data without error data in the original set of cells itself.

Comment: Question: I played around with the solution you posted and if you insert a column before column A, the cells in F, G, and H don't show the correct values even though it's referring to the same cells. Column F shows column B values, Column G shows Column C values, and so on. Am I missing something or does it have to do with the ctrl+shift+enter array formula?

Comment: After changing the columns, you'll need to reset the last part of the formula to refer to ROW(A1) and COLUMN(A1). These functions are used just to generate index numbers starting from 1, so regardless of where the data actually is, these functions always need to start from A1.

Comment: Yes, Michael, you are right. @Joyce, you may need to use this answer as a template, there were absolute references and relative references for some purposes. When You insert a column or extend the scope, you may need to change the references accordingly to reflect its purposes. This is nothing to do with the array formula. The purpose of A1 in the last part of the formula is to make the current cell to be inline with which row & which column of its corresponding source. It should be always the relative position of the source's top left column & it has to be always A1 as your source is from A1